# making an image of an suse32 computer and run it as virtual machine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I have an old suse32 computer. I want to remove the hardware but I need the System it selve.

Is it possible to make an image out of the old suse32 and run it afterwards in vm ware player or in virtual box?

If it is possible, how?

[image]

The new name is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about
[Physical-to-Virtual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical-to-Virtual)
using VMware.
However the Linux P2V tool of VMware, vCenter Converter, is no longer supported
for Linux.

You could do it yourself by :

1. Use `dd` to create an image of your source disk on external media
2. Create the target VM with the required hardware configuration
3. Boot the VM from a live Linux ISO
4. Partition and format the destination disk
5. `dd` from the external media to the destination disk
6. Make the destination VM bootable. This includes at least :

   - Fixing /etc/fstab mount entries
   - Fixing boot loader

Comment: Thanks, can you maybe give me some more detailed steps for point 5 and especially for 6? Thanks

Comment: This points were general in nature. It might be more economical to use a boot repair product such as [boot-repair-disk](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/).

Comment: Okay I have copied the harddrive made a vm harddrive out of the dd image. 

It boots now. But It does not find the harddrive. I added a screenshot above